# Can I say "the sofa was broken" when the foam of the sofa got loose and too stretchy to be usable?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, word-meaning

The word "[broken](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/broken)" has 2 meanings

> 1 : separated into parts or pieces by being hit, damaged, etc.
>
> The street was covered with broken glass.
>
> 2 : not working properly
>
> a broken camera

So, when you say "**The iphone is broken**" it could mean it is in pieces because you dropped it or it could mean it got malfunctioned (maybe because of its software error).

Now, I have a couch or a sofa which is not a machine. After using it for a long time, the foam of the sofa got loose and so stretchy that when I sat on it my bottom almost touched the floor.

So, the sofa was not literally broken in this case, but it was not usable.

I guess we can say "**the sofa was in bad repair**".

But I still want to ask this question:

Can we say "**the sofa was broken**" in this case?

Comment: I would say no.  A "broken sofa" is [something like this](https://previews.123rf.com/images/stocksnapper/stocksnapper0901/stocksnapper090100059/4247699-ugly-broken-and-dirty-couch-on-white.jpg).

Comment: I wouldn't use ***broken*** or ***busted*** in your context, because there are no moving parts (that no longer move as they should), and you can't point to an actual ***break*** (of a ***joint***, for example). How about ***clapped out, beat up, kaput, decrepit, crumbling, worn out,...*** ?  Or just ***useless*** (as you say yourself, "it was not usable").

Comment: The sofa has [**worn out**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/worn-out).